# Is there a way to access native APIs from renpy?

Tags: python, pyobjc, renpy

I'm currently using renpy and I want to access some features of the native NSWindow API (and eventually the win32 equivalent but I'm starting with the machine I'm using.) However PyObjC doesn't seem to be compatible, presumably because renpy's python implementation is not CPython, but I don't truly know. I asked in the discord and basically got a shrug so as a hail mary I'm gonna throw this question out to the people of stackoverflow:

Is there a way to access native APIs, like cocoa and win32, from renpy?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ren'Py is only compatible with libraries written in pure Python, so it's not possible at this point. PyObjC uses more than  just Python.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to accomplish?